# Using Python, how to check if a particular port is blocked by firewall on a remote host?

Tags: python, sockets, firewall, firewalld

My usecase for script is that from my local system I want to check wether a remote port is listening or not.

Expected behavior:

1. If port is listening, return '**listening**'
2. If no process is running on the port, return '**open**'
3. If port is blocked by firewalld, return '**blocked**'.

I tried checking for returncode in socket, but the codes are not consistent. I am getting a combination of 103, 103, 113 etc.